# Nested for-each in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I dont have much experience with XSLT. I need your help to prepare the correct XSL transformation for the below xml. I have XML like

```
<message>
<requisition>
    <data-values>
        <data-value multi-valued="false">
            <name>Test_Grid-1.Name</name>
            <value>1</value>
        </data-value>
        <data-value multi-valued="false">
            <name>Test_Grid-1.SupportType</name> 
            <value>Monthly,Quarterly</value>
        </data-value>
        <data-value multi-valued="false">
            <name>Test_Grid-1.Status</name>
            <value>New</value>
        </data-value>
        <data-value multi-valued="false">
            <name>Test_Grid-2.Name</name>
            <value>2</value>
        </data-value>
        <data-value multi-valued="false">
            <name>Test_Grid-2.SupportType</name> 
            <value>Monthly</value>
        </data-value>
        <data-value multi-valued="false">
            <name>Test_Grid-2.Status</name>
            <value>Existing</value>
        </data-value>
    </data-values>
</requisition>
<agent-parameter multi-valued="false">
    <name>ActionType</name>
    <value>New</value>
</agent-parameter>
<agent-parameter multi-valued="false">
    <name>Dictionary</name>
    <value>Test_Grid</value>
</agent-parameter>
<agent-parameter multi-valued="false">
    <name>ActionName</name>
    <value>SupportData</value>
</agent-parameter>
</message>
```

I want to prepare XML like this:

```
<ext:message>
<ext:record>
    <ext:name>SupportData</ext:name>
    <ext:rowData>
        <ext:rowAttribute name="Name">1</ext:rowAttribute>
        <ext:rowAttribute name="SupportType">Monthly,Quarterly</ext:rowAttribute>
        <ext:rowAttribute name="Status">New</ext:rowAttribute>
    </ext:rowData>
</ext:record>
<ext:record>
    <ext:name>SupportData</ext:name>
    <ext:rowData>
        <ext:rowAttribute name="Name">2</ext:rowAttribute>
        <ext:rowAttribute name="SupportType">Monthly</ext:rowAttribute>
        <ext:rowAttribute name="Status">Existing</ext:rowAttribute>
    </ext:rowData>
</ext:record>
```

Can you please help me with the XSL Transformation for this. Really appreciate your support.

Comment: Would it be possible to explain how the data is mapped in a little more detail, just to make sure everyone has understood the problem. For example, will there always be three elements per 'record' or can there be more? Is there a typo in your input XML, by the way, as the second 'name' element has a value of '1'. Should it be 2 to correspond with your output?

Comment: Also, are you using XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0 here?

Comment: Tim C, thats correct the second 'name' element has value of '2'. Sorry its a typo. Every record will have the name and rowData. The rowData element will have more sub-elements, for simplicity i gave only 3 elements in it. I am using XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be seen as a grouping problem. You have sequential elements, but you wish to group them by the **name** element (or rather, the part of the **name** element before the full stop which I assuming is the logic here). In XSLT 1.0 you would typically use a technique called [Muenchian Grouping](http://jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) to do this.

To start with, define a key that 'groups' the **data-value** elements by the relevant name.

```
<xsl:key name="record" match="data-value" use="substring-before(name, '.')" />
```

So, for a given name, such as "Test_Grid-2", the key will contain all the elements you need in a record.

To start outputting your records, you first have to look at all **data-value** elements, but select only the ones that occur first in the key for their given 'name'. Element comparison is done with the 'generate-id()' method, so the expression looks like this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
     select="requisition/data-values/data-value
     [generate-id() = 
        generate-id(key('record', substring-before(name, '.'))[1])]" mode="record" />
```

(The mode here is because the final XSLT will have two templates matching **data-value** so this will distinguish between them).

Then, within the template that matches the distinct **data-value** elements, you get all the elements for your record, like so

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('record', substring-before(name, '.'))" />
```

One thing to note, is your expected output is using the namespace prefix 'ext', but you haven't shown a declaration for the prefix. (Possibly because you were just simplifying your example), but I would actually expect the output to start like so:

```
<ext:message xmlns:ext="http://mylovelynamespace.com">
```

Anyway, try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ext="ext">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:key name="record" match="data-value" use="substring-before(name, '.')" />

   <xsl:template match="message">
      <ext:message>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="requisition/data-values/data-value[generate-id() = generate-id(key('record', substring-before(name, '.'))[1])]" mode="record" />
      </ext:message>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="data-value" mode="record">
      <ext:record>
         <ext:name>SupportData</ext:name>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="key('record', substring-before(name, '.'))" />
      </ext:record>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="data-value">
      <ext:rowAttribute name="{substring-after(name, '.')}"><xsl:value-of select="value" /></ext:rowAttribute>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In XSLT 2.0, you could use the **xsl:for-each-group** construct to simplify the grouping.

Comment: Muenchian Grouping is a very useful technique in XSLT 1.0, so just make sure you read up all about it!

Comment: while working with my actual xml i hit with a different scenario as below. The actual input xml contains different data-values (other than Test_Grid-1 or Test_Grid-2 etc). In that scenario the xsl is pulling all those elements and showing inside `<rowData>`. Is there any way i can set a variable and assign the value as "Test_Grid-" and the xsl will pull only those data-values where the name starts-with "Test_Grid-".

Comment: I tried something like below but its showing empty `<record>` elements in output like below.
`<ext:record>
   <ext:name>SupportData</ext:name>
 </ext:record>`
Is there a way i can show the `<record>` element only when it has some records in it.

Comment: I am sure it is possible, yes! But as this is a different scenario to the question as originally asked, you should really be asking a whole new question on StackOverflow. There's nothing wrong in doing that. Thanks!

Comment: I tried something like.. `$Dictionary` will have the value 'Test_Grid' assigned to it.
`   <xsl:template match="data-value">
<xsl:if test="starts-with(name,concat($Dictionary,'-'))">
 <ext:serviceItemAttribute name="{substring-after(name, '.')}"><xsl:value-of select="value" /></ext:serviceItemAttribute>
</xsl:if>`

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
<xsl:for-each select="data-value[position() mod 3 = 1]">
<ext:Record>
  <ext:name>...</ext:name>
  <ext:rowData>
    <ext:rowAttribute name="Name"><xsl:value-of select="substring(substring-after(name, 'Test-Grid_'), 1, 1)"/></ext:rowAttribute>
    <ext:rowAttribute name="SupportType"><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling[1]/value"/></ext:rowAttribute>
    <ext:rowAttribute name="Status"><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling[2]/value"/></ext:rowAttribute>
   </ext:rowData>
 </ext:Record>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Michael, thank you for the sample code. I dont want to hardcode the literal 'Test-Grid_', as this xml may have different value there, based on incoming request. Is there any way we can make it intelligent enough to figure out that from the xml?

Comment: If you can specify the rules then of course they can be coded. But it can't be intelligent enough to guess the specification (and nor can I).